# Differential inequality with assumption $|f'(t)|\le\sum_{i=1}^n b_i t^{\nu_i-1}(f(t))^{\theta_i}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

I am trying to show the following:

> Let $f\in C^1:(0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ satisfy
>   $$|f'(t)|\le\sum_{i=1}^n b_i t^{\nu_i-1}(f(t))^{\theta_i}$$
>   with $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $0\le\theta_i<1$, $\nu_i>0$, and $b_i\ge0$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.
>   Suppose that $f(t_1)=0$ for some $t_1>0$.
>   Then,
>   $$f(t)\le C\sum_{i=1}^n(b_i \nu_i^{-1}|t^{\nu_i}-t_1^{\nu_i}|)^{1/(1-\theta_i)}$$
>   for $t>0$ and some constant $C>0$.

The case $n=1$ follows from the separation of variables and the fundamental theorem of calculus. However, in the case $n\ge2$, this method does not hold in general.

I appreciate any advice.